# \nameref breaks for star versions of section/paragraph when titlesec is loaded

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, cross-referencing, titlesec

`\nameref` breaks for the `star` versions of `section`, `paragraph` when `titlesec` is loaded. I have a document that numbers paragraphs by default, but I have a few I do not want to number but would like to refer to. These are marked with `\paragraph*`, however, if the `titlesec` package is loaded at the same time, it causes `nameref` to display an empty string (the link box of hyperref is still visible).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[sf]{titlesec} %comment this out and it works fine.
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Sections}
\label{sec}
This is \nameref{sec}
\paragraph{A named Paragraph}
\label{par}
This is \nameref{par}
\paragraph*{A starred named Paragraph}
\label{par:star}
This is \nameref{par:star}
\end{document}
```

I suspect titlesec causes this defect for ALL star variants of sectioning commands but have not tested this. For me only `paragraph*` is relevant however a fix for all variants would be the best.

I have a hunch it might be related to this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6658/19326 however this happens to go way beyond my latex knowledge and is just "magic" for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ttl@useclass#1#2{%
  \@ifstar
    {\ttl@labeltrue\@dblarg{#1{#2}}}% {\ttl@labelfalse#1{#2}[]}%
    {\ttl@labeltrue\@dblarg{#1{#2}}}}
\makeatother
```

This allows for processing of the regular arguments `\<section>[<ToC>]{<regular>}` with the sectional unit `\<section>`. Additionally, setting `\ttl@labeltrue` inserts the appropriate [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) anchor.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[sf]{titlesec} %comment this out and it works fine.
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\ttl@useclass#1#2{%
  \@ifstar
    {\ttl@labelfalse\@dblarg{#1{#2}}}% {\ttl@labelfalse#1{#2}[]}%
    {\ttl@labeltrue\@dblarg{#1{#2}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Sections}
\label{sec}
This is \nameref{sec}
\paragraph{A named Paragraph}
\label{par}
This is \nameref{par}
\paragraph*{A starred named Paragraph}
\label{par:star}
This is \nameref{par:star}
\end{document}
```

Not extensively tested.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work ( I did not notice anything else breaking). Would you mind giving me a pointer were I could read/learn about `@useclass` , etc. so that I can understand what magic you used there? (googling `@useclass` turns up 2 results not related to tex, if you point me to a reference I am eager to learn by looking up the details myself rather than getting it laid out for me(Ihope to learn more that way))

Comment: it needed several (at least 5) reruns of pdflatex to make this fix work.

Comment: It appears that this has the same effect as removing the `*`, so that even starred sections become numbered.

Comment: @Teepeemm the first snippet of code is not the same as that used in the second snippet. The one in the second snippet worked for me and leaves the stared section unnumbered.