# How can I use the `\nameref{}` command for starred sections using the `titlesec`-package?

Tags: titlesec

I want to add subsubsections with alternative numbering (A1..A3, B1..B3, etc.) to my document. These subsubsections should be added to the `ToC`, but the native numbering should be suppressed, the alternative numbering should come onto the numberline.

I managed to do this with the `titlesec` package, but the breaks the `\nameref{}` command. A fix was suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123666/nameref-breaks-for-star-versions-of-section-paragraph-when-titlesec-is-loaded), but that makes the starred section also show up in the `ToC`, with original section-numbering.

How can I use the `\nameref{}` command for starred sections using the `titlesec`-package?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec} 

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\tempSectNumber\quad}

\newcommand{\mySubSubSection}[1]{\def\tempSectNumber{\thesubsubsection}\subsubsection{#1}\label{s:#1}}
\newcommand{\myStarredSubSubSection}[1]{\def\tempSectNumber{X1}\subsubsection*{#1}\label{s:#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\protect{\numberline{X1}}#1}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\mySubSubSection{Normal}
\myStarredSubSubSection{Special}

Reference to Normal: \autoref{s:Normal}/\nameref{s:Normal}\par
Reference to Special: \autoref{s:Special}/\nameref{s:Special}\par
\end{document}
```

Desired outcome:

```
Contents
0.0.1 Normal  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .   1
X1    Special . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .   1

0.0.1  Normal
X1  Special

Reference to Normal: subsubsection 0.0.1/Normal
Reference to Special: subsubsection 0.0.1/Special
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step the `subsubsection` counter in order to trigger the `\label`-`ref` mechanism, define `\@currentlabelname` and `\@currentlabel` to the desired values.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\tempSectNumber\quad}

\newcommand{\mySubSubSection}[1]{%
  \def\tempSectNumber{\thesubsubsection}%
  \subsubsection{#1}%
  \label{s:#1}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myStarredSubSubSection}[1]{%
  \def\tempSectNumber{X1}%
  \refstepcounter{subsubsection}%
  \subsubsection*{#1}%
  \addtocounter{subsubsection}{-1}%
  \def\@currentlabelname{#1}%
  \def\@currentlabel{\thesubsubsection}%
  \label{s:#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\protect{\numberline{X1}}#1}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\mySubSubSection{Normal}
\myStarredSubSubSection{Special}

Reference to Normal: \autoref{s:Normal}/\nameref{s:Normal}\par
Reference to Special: \autoref{s:Special}/\nameref{s:Special}\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

I discourage from setting labels this way. If your title contains special characters you're doomed. And labels should be mnemonics.

Comment: That did it, thank you! I set the `\myStarredSubSubSection` to a two variable command, giving in the section number manually and set that as label. That prevents doom when using special characters in the title.

`\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myStarredSubSubSection}[2]{%
    \def\tempSectNumber{#2}%
    \subsubsection*{#1}%
    \addtocounter{subsubsection}{-1}%
    \def\@currentlabelname{#1}%
    \def\@currentlabel{\thesubsubsection}%
    \label{#2}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\protect{\numberline{#2}}#1}%
}
\makeatother`