# Nameref does not work with StylishArticle

Tags: hyperref, appendices, nameref

I have used the [StylishArticle](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/stylish-article) class several times, but I recently thought it would be a good idea to reference sections based on their names instead of using sections numbers or `pageref`.

So I defined `\newcommand{\appref}[1]{Appendix:\nameref{#1}}` for use with `\subsection*` (not numbered), and tested it with a normal article class. Seems to be working fine.

However when I use it with StylishArticle, it doesn't seem to work so well, and I get a warning:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Suppressing empty link on input line 86.
```

[This link](https://www.overleaf.com/read/btvdfwcvrxhx) will get you to an Overleaf document (read-only) so you can see for yourself. I tried to keep the example small, but I don't think it's minimal; I need help identifying what's causing this issue. Any help greatly appreciated!

---

Following @egreg suggestion, here is a much shorter MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\appref}[1]{Appendix:\nameref{#1}}

\begin{document}

    \section{A normal section}
    Reference to \appref{app}.

    \phantomsection
    \section*{Appendices}
    \label{app}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Sh3ljohn The life time of the link target can be different of the life time of the question. Therefore, it is better to include the short document in the question text.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Please see the latest edit, sorry about the length, but that's as short as it gets if I should include the class-file.

Comment: I can easily make up a non working example with the `article` class, by just loading `titlesec`.

Comment: @egreg Very sorry, but I don't know how to do that. :/

Comment: Might be a duplicate of: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/284595/26497

Comment: @Sh3ljohn `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{titlesec}\usepackage{hyperref}`, then the definition of `\appref` and the same body as your test document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/284596/26497), the following definitions did it for me, although this implied using `\appsubsec{name}{app:label}` instead of the usual `\subsection*{name}\label{app:label}`.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\appsec}[2]{%
  \phantomsection
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \section*{#1}%
  \addtocounter{section}{-1}%
  \def\@currentlabelname{App: #1}%
  \def\@currentlabel{\thesection}%
  \label{#2}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\appsubsec}[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{subsection}%
  \subsection*{#1}%
  \addtocounter{subsection}{-1}%
  \def\@currentlabelname{App: #1}%
  \def\@currentlabel{\thesubsection}%
  \label{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\appsubsubsec}[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{subsubsection}%
  \subsubsection*{#1}%
  \addtocounter{subsubsection}{-1}%
  \def\@currentlabelname{App: #1}%
  \def\@currentlabel{\thesubsubsection}%
  \label{#2}%
}
\makeatother
```

These commands make sure that only `appsec` (the equivalent of `section*`) is entered into the table of contents, so that you only see one entry `Appendices` (which should be defined in your document to mark the beginning of appendices), and not each appendix listed as a normal subsection.

Note that these commands *require* a label (the second input is not optional), and that calling `\nameref{app:label}` in your document will yield a link with text `App: name`.

Comment: Thank you! And I just want to throw this out there for anyone else; **make sure you use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`** or you won't get any effect.

Answer (score 2):

From `hyperref`'s [`README`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README.pdf):

> ### `titlesec`
>
> `nameref` supports `titlesec`, but `hyperref` does not   (unsolved is the anchor setting, missing with unnumbered   section,
>   perhaps problems with page breaks with numbered ones).

Comment: Right, so there is no way I can link the names of my unnumbered sections then?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn Does the [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/284596/16967) of the [duplicate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332251/nameref-does-not-work-with-stylisharticle/332267?noredirect=1#comment814266_332251), [found](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332251/nameref-does-not-work-with-stylisharticle/332267?noredirect=1#comment814266_332251) by you, works for you?

Comment: Sorry for being so demanding, but although I understand that `titlesec` is causing the issue, and I understand that @egreg defined new commands for subsubsections, I am not sure how to implement this in the class-file linked in the OP.. I can see a `titleformat` definition in there for (sub(sub))sections, but there is also a special definition for `\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}` and I don't know how to adapt the answer from the duplicate to that case.