# How to use the package etoc to create local toc's?

Tags: table-of-contents

I need to write a very large document, and I would like use etoc to create local tocs.
(the minitoc is incompatible in my doc;)

how i can create a local list of table and figures?

why nameref gets wrong reference in this mwe?

when I use a unnumbered part (\part*{Appendix}) the command \localtableofcontents show a empty table and the previous table of contents list the appendix content, how can I correct it?

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{nameref}

\titleclass{\part}{top} % make part like a chapter
\titleformat{\part}
[display]
{\centering\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
{\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{3pt}\titlerule[1pt]\vspace{3pt}\MakeUppercase{\partname} \thepart}
{0pt}
{\titlerule[1pt]\vspace{1pc}\huge\MakeUppercase}
%
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures\newpage
\listoftables\newpage
\tableofcontents\newpage


\etocmulticolstyle{\noindent\bfseries\footnotesize
\leaders\hrule height1pt\hfill
\MakeUppercase{Contents}}
\etocsettocdepth{1}

\part{FIRST PART}\label{part:one}
%how to make a localtableofcontents of figures and tables?
\localtableofcontents
\chapter{INTRODUCTION} \lipsum{1}
\chapter{METHODOLOGY} \lipsum{1}
\chapter{CONCLUSION} \lipsum{1}


\part{SECOND PART}
%how to make a localtableofcontents of figures and tables?
\localtableofcontents
\chapter{INTRODUCTION} 
Like in \nameref{part:one}.% why nameref gets the wrong reference? 
\lipsum{1}

\chapter{METHODOLOGY} \lipsum{1}
\chapter{CONCLUSION} \lipsum{1}

\appendix
\part{APPENDIX}
%how to make a localtableofcontents of appendix
\localtableofcontents
\chapter{document a}
\chapter{document B}
\end{document}
```

thank u : )

Comment: are you open to a solution using `titletoc`, which is a sibbling to `titlesec`?

Comment: i try to use \startcontents[parts]
\printcontents[parts]{} before \part and in the end \stopcontents[parts], but it doesn't worked. well, i'm open to a solution using titletoc and titlesec. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(*update: `etoc 1.07k` incorporates compatibility with `tocloft`; see bottom of answer *)

The [etoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc) package at the time of writing does not hook into list of figures or list of tables, but only handles tables of contents.

With an unnumbered Appendix part, the usual `addcontentsline` should be used

```
\part*{APPENDIX}
\addcontentsline {toc}{part}{APPENDIX}
```

Note that without it, even the main `\tableofcontents` without `etoc` would look strange anyhow, as the chapters of the appendix would appear right in the continuation of the previous ones (albeit with Alpha numbering).

Nevertheless it is also possible to obtain a local table of contents in the `APPENDIX` part, without having an `APPENDIX` entry in the main table of contents.

At the main table of contents command:

```
\etocsetlevel{appendixplaceholder}{6}
\tableofcontents
\etocsetlevel{appendixplaceholder}{-1}
```

And:

```
\part*{APPENDIX}
\etoctoccontentsline*{appendixplaceholder}{APPENDIX}{-1}
% the above works with or without hyperref. If the document does not use
% hyperref, then
% \addcontentsline{toc}{appendixplaceholder}{APPENDIX}
% is an alternative
\localtableofcontents
```

With this:

1. the local table of contents is created as desired
2. there is no APPENDIX entry in the main table of contents
3. there is a correct APPENDIX bookmark in the pdf output.

However `3.` would not be true with the set-up of your `mwe` due to some interaction between the  `\titleclass` and `\titleformat` commands of `titlesec` and `hyperref`. There is something dysfunctional there, I did not investigate further.

And for `nameref` not getting the correct reference, this is unrelated to `etoc`, as one can see by not loading it and commenting out all relevant portions.

This is a `titlesec` issue which is addressed in [cmhughes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6621/cmhughes) 's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163551/4686).

---

*`etoc`--`tocloft` compatibility:*

The `tocloft` package was mentioned in a comment. Although the `etoc` manual always said that one could use `tocloft` to customize the toc lines when `etoc` was left in compatibility mode, it forgot to say that the user had to do `\let\tableofcontents\etoctableofcontents` to counteract the overwriting by `tocloft` of `\tableofcontents` done at  `\begin{document}`.

Anyway, release `1.07k` of [etoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc) provides transparently the compatibility with `tocloft`, which should be loaded before `etoc` (else a warning is issued as `tocloft` will be forced into its "`titles`" mode). Then, in compatibility mode, `tocloft` customization for the toc lines, and for the toc title, will be obeyed faithfully by `etoc`. The user may still benefit from other aspects of `etoc` such as its `\localtableofcontents` (also obeying the `tocloft` customization current at that point of the document), and its `\label+\ref` mechanism. And it is possible to use `tocloft` for one TOC and `etoc` for another one. Besides, naturally, `tocloft` dealings with `list of figures` and `list of tables` will be completely untouched by `etoc`.

Comment: it works perfectly in mwe. sadly tocloft and etoc are incompatible.

Comment: @user42634 I am glad stuff is working, but I am not sure I know what you are referring too: perhaps the `\addcontentsline` thing? another thing when you say `tocloft` and `etoc` are incompatible, your `mwe` uses `titlesec` not `tocloft`, perhaps you mean *I would like to use `tocloft+etoc` but I can't*. Try the following: immediately after `\begin{document}` insert `\let\tableofcontents\etoctableofcontents`. Then the main toc will be governed by `etoc` but all customizing done via `tocloft` to the way parts and chapters are to be printed will be obeyed.

Comment: thanks for the tip. you're right, i was trying to say "I would like to use tocloft+etoc but I can't". Now with the command \let\tableofcontents\etoctableofcontents, i did not miss the customization done with the package tocloft in TOC. awesome!

Comment: i used the command 
\etocmulticolstyle[1]{\centering\normalsize\bfseries\MakeUppercase{Table of Contents}} to customize the TOC title. how to adjust the vertical align?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13384/discussion-between-user42634-and-jfbu)

Comment: try with `\renewcommand\etocinnertopsep{5ex}` (adjust `5ex` to the desired value).

Comment: @user42634 release `1.07k` of `etoc` will be compatible with `tocloft` out of the box. No need for the `\etoctableofcontents` thing, and the `tocloft` customizing will be obeyed for the title too, not only the contents.

Comment: very thanks man! now i'm trying to do the lof and the lot with etoc! but it seems a bit complicated :)

Comment: @user42634 `etoc` is ignorant of the `.lof` and `.lot` files, it is possible to use `etoc` to typeset a `List of Figures` and a `List of Tables` using suitable `addcontentsline` and `\etocsetlevel`, [this isn't even properly explained in the `etoc` manual] but the more reasonable is definitely to wait two or three days until `etoc 1.07k` reaches your installation, then you can just employ `tocloft` to customize `LOF` and `LOT` in the usual way.

Comment: in my tex files main LOF and LOT are already customized... but i want the local lof and lot in the same style of local toc.

Comment: you can achieve that with suitable `\etocsetlevel` magic, if each table or figure does a suitable `\addcontentsline {toc}` or perhaps `\etoctoccontentsline` to avoir additional hyperref bookmark.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution using the [`titletoc`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/titletoc) package. The important parts are:

```
% local tableofcontents
\section*{Local toc}
\startcontents[mytoc]
\printcontents[mytoc]{}{0}{}

% local listoffigures
\section*{Local lof}
\startlist[mylof]{lof}
\printlist[mylof]{lof}{0}{}

% local listoftables
\section*{Local lot}
\startlist[mylot]{lot}
\printlist[mylot]{lot}{0}{}

... <part content goes here>
... <part content goes here>
... <part content goes here>

% stop local toc, lof, lot
\stopcontents[mytoc]
\stoplist[mylof]{lof}
\stoplist[mylot]{lot}
```

This creates partial `toc`, `lof`, and `lot`.

Here's a complete MWE that demonstrates the idea- you'll need to run it twice, or else run it with [`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara) which will compile it twice for you.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titleclass{\part}{top} % make part like a chapter
\titleformat{\part}
[display]
{\centering\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
{\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{3pt}\titlerule[1pt]\vspace{3pt}\MakeUppercase{\partname} \thepart}
{0pt}
{\titlerule[1pt]\vspace{1pc}\huge\MakeUppercase}
%
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

\makeatletter
\let\titlesec@part\part
\renewcommand{\part}{\@ifstar\part@star\part@nostar}
\def\part@star#1{\NR@gettitle{#1}\titlesec@part*{#1}}
\def\part@nostar{\@ifnextchar[\part@nostar@opt\part@nostar@nopt}
\def\part@nostar@nopt#1{\NR@gettitle{#1}\titlesec@part{#1}}
\def\part@nostar@opt[#1]#2{\NR@gettitle{#2}\titlesec@part[#1]{#2}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\tableofcontents



\part{FIRST PART}\label{part:one}
% local tableofcontents
% local tableofcontents
% local tableofcontents
\section*{Local toc}
\startcontents[mytoc]
\printcontents[mytoc]{}{0}{}

% local listoffigures
% local listoffigures
% local listoffigures
\section*{Local lof}
\startlist[mylof]{lof}
\printlist[mylof]{lof}{0}{}

% local listoftables
% local listoftables
% local listoftables
\section*{Local lot}
\startlist[mylot]{lot}
\printlist[mylot]{lot}{0}{}
\chapter{INTRODUCTION} \lipsum{1}
\chapter{METHODOLOGY} \lipsum{1}
\chapter{CONCLUSION} \lipsum{1}
\newcount\tmp
\tmp=0
\loop
\advance\tmp by 1
\begin{table}[!htb]\caption{table in part I}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[!htb]\caption{figure in part I}\end{figure}
\ifnum\tmp<5 \repeat

% stop local toc, lof, lot
\stopcontents[mytoc]
\stoplist[mylof]{lof}
\stoplist[mylot]{lot}

\part{SECOND PART}
% local tableofcontents
% local tableofcontents
% local tableofcontents
\section*{Local toc}
\startcontents[mytoc]
\printcontents[mytoc]{}{0}{}

% local listoffigures
% local listoffigures
% local listoffigures
\section*{Local lof}
\startlist[mylof]{lof}
\printlist[mylof]{lof}{0}{}

% local listoftables
% local listoftables
% local listoftables
\section*{Local lot}
\startlist[mylot]{lot}
\printlist[mylot]{lot}{0}{}
\chapter{INTRODUCTION} 
Like in \nameref{part:one}.% why nameref gets the wrong reference? 
\lipsum{1}

\chapter{METHODOLOGY} \lipsum{1}
\chapter{CONCLUSION} \lipsum{1}
\tmp=0
\loop
\advance\tmp by 1
\begin{table}[!htb]\caption{table in part II}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[!htb]\caption{figure in part II}\end{figure}
\ifnum\tmp<5 \repeat

% stop local toc, lof, lot
\stopcontents[mytoc]
\stoplist[mylof]{lof}
\stoplist[mylot]{lot}

\appendix
\part{APPENDIX}
% local tableofcontents
% local tableofcontents
% local tableofcontents
\section*{Local toc}
\startcontents[mytoc]
\printcontents[mytoc]{}{0}{}

% local listoffigures
% local listoffigures
% local listoffigures
\section*{Local lof}
\startlist[mylof]{lof}
\printlist[mylof]{lof}{0}{}

% local listoftables
% local listoftables
% local listoftables
\section*{Local lot}
\startlist[mylot]{lot}
\printlist[mylot]{lot}{0}{}

\chapter{document a}
\chapter{document B}
\tmp=0
\loop
\advance\tmp by 1
\begin{table}[!htb]\caption{Table}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[!htb]\caption{Figure}\end{figure}
\ifnum\tmp<5 \repeat

% stop local toc, lof, lot
\stopcontents[mytoc]
\stoplist[mylof]{lof}
\stoplist[mylot]{lot}
\end{document}
```

I have also pasted some code from [Problems with part-labels using titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/problems-with-part-labels-using-titlesec) to fix the `nameref` for `\part`.

Comment: very good solution!! thanks. just one little thing, i ran your mwe and the problem on this line continue:

\chapter{INTRODUCTION} 
Like in \nameref{part:one}.% why nameref gets the wrong reference? 
\lipsum{1}

why?

Comment: @user42634 glad you like it- see the update for a fix for `nameref` :)

Comment: this mwe works fine, and i understood de code. but there is a conflict when I paste this code in my tex files. do you know some incompatibility between titletoc and another package? 
when i compile, the console show: ! Paragraph ended before \@writefile was complete.

Comment: @user42634 it's going to be hard to know the problem without a complete MWE; it is very possible that `titletoc` is not compatible with another `tableofcontents` package- are you sure you need more than one package to customize your `toc`?

Comment: i need to customize the tocloft title's... I need to write their titles in uppercase and adjust the horizontal and vertical align.
i'm using titlesec, titletoc,tocloft

Comment: @user42634 your MWE doesn't contain `tocloft`; it might be worth opening another question given that your current question (as you've written it) has been addressed