# Set tocdepth for local table of contents for part heading page

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, titletoc

I am using a part of the MWE from  [How to use the package etoc to create local toc's?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163550/how-to-use-the-package-etoc-to-create-local-tocs) I would like to know how to set the tocdepth.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titleclass{\part}{top} % make part like a chapter
\titleformat{\part}
[display]
{\centering\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
{\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{3pt}\titlerule[1pt]\vspace{3pt}\MakeUppercase{\partname} \thepart}
{0pt}
{\titlerule[1pt]\vspace{1pc}\huge\MakeUppercase}
%
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

\makeatletter
\let\titlesec@part\part
\renewcommand{\part}{\@ifstar\part@star\part@nostar}
\def\part@star#1{\NR@gettitle{#1}\titlesec@part*{#1}}
\def\part@nostar{\@ifnextchar[\part@nostar@opt\part@nostar@nopt}
\def\part@nostar@nopt#1{\NR@gettitle{#1}\titlesec@part{#1}}
\def\part@nostar@opt[#1]#2{\NR@gettitle{#2}\titlesec@part[#1]{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\part{FIRST PART}\label{part:one}
\section*{Local toc}
\startcontents[mytoc]
\printcontents[mytoc]{}{0}{}
\chapter{INTRODUCTION} \lipsum{1}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\chapter{METHODOLOGY} \lipsum{1}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\chapter{CONCLUSION} \lipsum{1}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` to include to subsection depth, `{1}` to section depth, and `{0}` to chapter depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal method of adjusting the tocdepth is `\setcounter{tocdepth}{...}`. I have shown some possibilities based on your MWE.

```
% titletocprob.tex  SE 597613

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titleclass{\part}{top} % make part like a chapter
\titleformat{\part}
[display]
{\centering\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
{\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{3pt}\titlerule[1pt]\vspace{3pt}\MakeUppercase{\partname} \thepart}
{0pt}
{\titlerule[1pt]\vspace{1pc}\huge\MakeUppercase}
%
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

\makeatletter
\let\titlesec@part\part
\renewcommand{\part}{\@ifstar\part@star\part@nostar}
\def\part@star#1{\NR@gettitle{#1}\titlesec@part*{#1}}
\def\part@nostar{\@ifnextchar[\part@nostar@opt\part@nostar@nopt}
\def\part@nostar@nopt#1{\NR@gettitle{#1}\titlesec@part{#1}}
\def\part@nostar@opt[#1]#2{\NR@gettitle{#2}\titlesec@part[#1]{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\part{FIRST PART}\label{part:one}
\section*{Local toc}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} % down to subparagraphs
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % down to sections
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0} % down to chapters

\startcontents[mytoc]
\printcontents[mytoc]{}{0}{}
\chapter{INTRODUCTION} \lipsum{1}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\chapter{METHODOLOGY} \lipsum{1}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\chapter{CONCLUSION} \lipsum{1}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\end{document}
```

[image]