# Problems with \nameref{} not refering to the correct label x titlesec

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, titlesec

I'm using hyperref package to do cross-referencing, but I'm encountering some problems and it is related to `\usepackage{titlesec,titleps}` , for instance:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec,titleps} %If I remove the \titleclass for \part it works fine!
\titleclass{\part}{top}\titleformat{\part}{\centering\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection\hspace{3pt}$\vert$}{3pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\slshape}{\thesubsection\hspace{3pt}$\vert$}{3pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont}{\thesubsubsection\hspace{3pt}$\vert$}{3pt}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont\slshape}{\theparagraph\hspace{3pt}$\vert$}{3pt}{}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}{\normalfont}{\thesubparagraph\hspace{3pt}$\vert$}{3pt}{}{}

\begin{document}
\part{Part One}
\label{P1}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\label{C1}
\section{Section One}
\label{S1}
Here the cross-reference for \autoref{C1} "\nameref{C1}" and \autoref{S1} "\nameref{S1}" work fine, but not for \autoref{P1} "\nameref{P1}".

As also for \autoref{C2} "\nameref{C2}" and \autoref{S2} "\nameref{S2}", but not for \autoref{P2} "\nameref{P2}".\\

\part{Part Two}
\label{P2}
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\label{C2}
\section{Section Two}
\label{S2}

\end{document}
```

So if I cross-reference to `\nameref{P2}` from anywhere in "Part One" it gives the name of the "Section One" (the last before Part Two, if I remove that section it goes to the one before it), while the "Part II" from the `\autoref{P2}` is right. If I refer to  `\nameref{P1}` in "Part One" it gives me the error "??".
**Is there a way to know what is going on?** Thanks for your help and attention!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the problem is with the \titleclass for the \part, is there a work around for it? Or maybe is it a bug?

Comment: thanks for editing the example, it should be much easier to fix now (someone if not me, I can confirm I see same in texlive 2014)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure which package is breaking what, but `\part` ends up not saving the part name in a form that `nameref` can use. This just redefines it to save it explicitly, it assumes you don't need `*` or `[]` argument forms of `\part`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{titlesec,titleps} %If I remove the \titleclass for \part it works fine!
%\titleclass{\part}{top}\titleformat{\part}{\centering\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection\hspace{3pt}$\vert$}{3pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\slshape}{\thesubsection\hspace{3pt}$\vert$}{3pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont}{\thesubsubsection\hspace{3pt}$\vert$}{3pt}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont\slshape}{\theparagraph\hspace{3pt}$\vert$}{3pt}{}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}{\normalfont}{\thesubparagraph\hspace{3pt}$\vert$}{3pt}{}{}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\let\oldpart\part
\def\part#1{\def\@currentlabelname{#1}\oldpart{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\part{Part One}
\label{P1}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\label{C1}
\section{Section One}
\label{S1}
Here the cross-reference for \autoref{C1} "\nameref{C1}" and \autoref{S1} "\nameref{S1}" work fine, but not for \autoref{P1} "\nameref{P1}".

As also for \autoref{C2} "\nameref{C2}" and \autoref{S2} "\nameref{S2}", but not for \autoref{P2} "\nameref{P2}".\\

\part{Part Two}
\label{P2}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\label{C2}
\section{Section Two}
\label{S2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your macro works even with the `\titleclass` on. Another important aspect also was to load `\usepackage{hyperref}` after the `\usepackage{titlesec}` it solved another issue I was having with `\usepackage{titletoc}` to inset a TOC in the `\part` page. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @David Carlisle: unfortunately, `classicthesis`does not work together with your solution. Do you know what I should do to use `\nameref` referring to `\part{}\label{}` when using `classicthesis` (texlive 2015)? The relevant code section in `classicthesis.sty` (lines 600-632) does not look very promising.

Comment: I had the same problem in the package  `beamer`, `\nameref` did not show the name of the "part". This `\part` redefinition solved it seamlessly.

Comment: Probably related https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6658/167404

Comment: @Hotschke and others ending up here looking for a solution for `classicthesis`: The solution mentioned in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6658 works for `classicthesis`.